# Cucumber and rails: testing for the presence of a random record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, cucumber, capybara

I have an app that displays some content and then selects a random record and shows it

How do I test for this?

```
Then /^I Should see the associated "([^']*)" "([^']*)"$/ do |type, elements|
    elements.split(', ').each do |element|
        page.should have_content element
    end
end
```

obviously fails as it doesn't find every record. How do I validate the presence of only one record??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
Then /^I should see the associated "([^"]*)" "([^"]*)"$/ do |type, elements|
  found = false
  elements.split(', ').each do |element|
    found = true if page.has_content? element
  end
  found.should == true
end
```